# What does the superscript triangle (△) symbol mean in graph/causality notation?

Tags: causality, graphical-model, intervention-analysis

I am reading a paper called [Robustly Disentangled Causal Mechanisms: Validating Deep Representations for Interventional Robustness](https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.00007) and in stating a proposition the authors use a triangle superscript notation (above g_j) when referring to interventions on a random variable:

[image: Proposition 1]

However, the paper also refers to interventions without the triangle superscript like in the definition below:

[image: PIDA]

I was wondering whether someone has come across this notation in the past or knows what the superscript triangle refers to, so I can make sense of the differences in the notation.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It's just an idiosyncratic way to create a symbol distinct from "$g."$ The list item (e) *defines* $g_j^\Delta$ as a bound variable in a quantifier.

Comment: @Tim The quoted section is a perfectly fine definition.  It accords with the rules of mathematical notation.  If anyone is uncomfortable with it, they could replace "$g_j^\Delta$" by any (unique) symbol they like, such as the usual "$x.$"